# SSIS block unsigned packages

Tags: ssis

I am trying to configure SSIS for SQL Server 2014 to block unsigned packages from running. Based on the links below my understanding is to add the registry DWORD BlockedSignatureStates and set it to 3.

- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/securing-sql-server-2012-integration-services-packages-using-digital-certificates.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403378(v=sql.120).aspx

Based on my research there is conflicting directions as to where to put this DWORD. So, I have tried putting the DWORD in all of the following locations:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SSIS
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SSIS\MSDTS
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SSIS
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SSIS\MSDTS
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SSIS
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SSIS\MSDTS

Each location has not been successful.

Some background: I do have unsigned packages that I'm using for testing and they run when they ideally shouldn't. I also have trusted signed packages that run successfully. It seems that no matter what I do there is no impact to what can and cannot run. It does however block untrusted signed packages from running but I believe that is the default configuration.

Comment: Did you also do the configurations by running `Regedit`?

Comment: Yes, all were done using regedit.